# update merge onetomany jpa/hibernate - ConstraintViolationImpl

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, merge

I am trying to make a simple update of a list in jpa, but it is not working.
I have something like.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@DynamicUpdate 
public class User implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<UserLangs> userLangsList;

}
```

and the table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_langs")
public class UserLangs implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "foreign")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "foreign",
        strategy = "foreign",
        parameters = {
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "property", value = "user")
        })
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private Long userid;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Id
    @Column(name = "lang")
    private String lang;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "level")
    private int level;

    @JoinColumn(
        name = "userid",
        referencedColumnName = "id",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;
```

so when i tried to update the list `UserLangs` from the User Object get the following exepction:

```
WARNING - Unexpected exception from beforeCompletion; transaction will roll back

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: error during managed flush
at  org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1515)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:117)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53)
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforeCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:527)
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforeCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:511)
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:413)
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:262)
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:252)
at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.JtaTransactionPolicy.completeTransaction(JtaTransactionPolicy.java:328)
at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.TxRequired.commit(TxRequired.java:75)
at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil.afterInvoke(EjbTransactionUtil.java:73)
at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:257)
at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:189)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:253)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:248)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:92)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:279)
at com.polyglong.dao.UsersDAO$LocalBeanProxy.updateUser(com/polyglong/dao/UsersDAO.java)
at com.polyglong.dao.UserDAOTest.getUpdateUser(UserDAOTest.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:45)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
  Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.polyglong.entities.user.UserLangs] during persist time for groups   [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
      List of constraint violations:[
ConstraintViolationImpl{rootBean=com.polyglong.entities.UserLangs[  userid=4,lang=null,level=0 ], propertyPath='lang', message='may not be null', leafBean=com.polyglong.entities.UserLangs[ userid=4,lang=null,level=0 ], value=null}
   ]
at        org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventLi stener.java:159)
at        org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:94)
at       org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:181)
at   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:81)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:275)
at        org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:328)
at                    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1233)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:403)
at               org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:112)
... 47 more
```

according to the execption the lang its trying to be setted as null, but that its the strange part, since everything its setted properly and there are no null in the object but for some reason after the commit it rolls back.

the merge works properly when trying to update just the object user, but when i tried to update the userlangs list inside it fails.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You marked the lang property as @NotNull, but you are attempting to save one that is null.  The error you are getting is a constraint violation saying such.

Comment: but thats the thing, i am not trying to save any as null.
it is setted with a value, even though the error says its null.
I made a debug and it has the proper value until the merge.

Comment: can you check all the entities?  If you are using an IDE, perhaps setup a break on the exception, see which entity is balking?  Since you have references to other Entities w/ CascadeType.ALL set, it's possible that you are getting the error saving this entity, but the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: yeah i tried doing that, but its not getting inside the catch.
It looks like it will be a successfull merge, and suddenly rollsback

Comment: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a synchronization

Comment: The thing that sticks out to me is this part of the exception:  [  userid=4,lang=null,level=0 ], propertyPath='lang', message='may not be null'.  That is telling me that the exception that caused the rollback was a validation problem with the "lang" value being null.  Try taking off the @NotNull and seeing if it works.  You may need to update the table to accept a null value, just for the test.

Comment: Well it seems hibernate its adding internally some values as null, maybe to delete the element.
And it gives exeception since the field lang its an Id field..
 `//  @NotNull
    @Id
    @Column(name = "lang")
    private String lang;`

When i delete the @Id, it commit successfully, but just adding the fields in UserLangs to the database if they are not there, not updating or deleting the ones that are not in the List<UserLangs>, even though im doing merge.